# recovering transmission from lost TCP connection

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am working on client server application written in C for Linux where I am replicating the data to multiple slave replicas using TCP and I would like to know how to deal with  unexpected temporary shutdown of some replica (it may be the crash of the unix process or hardware power off).

When I issue the write() syscall to the kernel, the successful return means the data was copied to the socket, but doesn't mean that the receiving end *got* the data. If the destination is powered off and then powered up, the data must be resent (after establishing a new TCP connection) to the replica from the point where it lost the data.

Lets say I am working with large data amounts and I don't keep the data that I already sent (i.e. the write() syscall returned success). I keep only the pending data to be sent.

When the replica recovers from the unexpected shutdown and connects again, how do I get, from kernel, the data that has been written to the socket, but wasn't 'ack'-nowledged on the destination host, yet?

Or in other words, how do I recover from a loss of a TCP connection and reestablish transmission between client and server from the point where it stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP will take care of the sequence numbers needed for TCP, you can't make much use of those at the application level

You need some sequence control at the application level.

In your case here, you could assign a number to each block of data you sent. The destination need to keep persistent track of the last block number it has received. On startup from an unexpected shutdown, the destination need to communicate back the last blocknumber it processed, and you start sending from there.

> how do I get from the kernel the data that has been written to the socket, but wasn't 'ack'-nowledged on the destination host yet?

Even if you could, this would not be enough. The destination host might very well have acked' the data, but for whatever reason the ack could be lost, or never sent, but the destination application could have received and processed that data fine. So if you use the TCP sequence number in this case, you'd end up with duplicated data.

An other case is that TCP sent back an ack for the data, and the destination application crashed/shutdown just as it read that data, but right before it wrote it to disk. So you end up with lost data.

Comment: [Write-ahead log protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) is used to ensure safety.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another level of abstraction on top of TCP. After every piece of data is sent (TCP guarantees that it will get there intact and in order), have the process at the other end send it's own kind of ACK, in your own higher level protocol (whatever that is -- be it "ACK\0", "GOT\n" or anything else). On the other side (the originator), read for this data. If it comes through good without error, everything's fine. If you get an error -- check the type. If you get ECONNRESET, that means that the remote end is dead. From this, you can respond accordingly. Wait until you can reconnect, and repeat the data send all over again.

Comment: If I have to implement my own TCP on top of TCP itself, it makes me think maybe UDP is better in this case.

Comment: @Nulik: NO! (Please don't use UDP! Please!). UDP doesn't guarantee that anything *ever* gets *anywhere*, or that it gets there in *any* order, or that it's even *sent* in the first place! This is not a TCP on top of TCP, this is a small application level protocol taking advantage of all of the features of TCP. Please don't reimplement TCP. The OS implementations have been honed and perfected by hundreds of experts. Don't try to redo their work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do what you want through the standard API.

A solution could be to have you client periodically send back a running total of bytes received and verified written to disc, and then keep a buffer of sent but not acknowledge data on the server. Then when the client reconnects, it sends it last good count, and the server knows where to start retransmitting.